# how to form multiple log formats based on severity level for a specific destination - python logging

Tags: python, logging, formatting

I'm a beginner in python and logging using logging package.
I want to send info logs with a specific format differ from other levels  (for example: debug, warning, ...) **to a specific destination** (for example: standard output).
I've understood up to now that each handler only captures one log style.
Is it possible to partition log levels to some sets and assign specific format to each set.
Thanks